# Symbol not found when using ruby gem berkshelf

Tags: ruby, rubygems, berkshelf

I have been having general issues with berkshelf, namely the dependancy solver problem that you can read more about [here](https://github.com/berkshelf/solve/issues/27)

Now that issue has been solved I've just tried to do a bundle install/update and a berks install to try out the new dependancy solver but I'm getting a strange error when i do a berks install:

```
➜  deployment git:(master) ✗ berks install
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/ffi-1.9.3/lib/ffi/library.rb:133:in `block in ffi_lib': Could not open library '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/dep_selector-1.0.0.alpha.2/lib/dep_gecode.bundle': dlopen(/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/dep_selector-1.0.0.alpha.2/lib/dep_gecode.bundle, 5): Symbol not found: __ZN6Gecode16ValBranchOptions3defE (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/dep_selector-1.0.0.alpha.2/lib/dep_gecode.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/dep_selector-1.0.0.alpha.2/lib/dep_gecode.bundle
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/ffi-1.9.3/lib/ffi/library.rb:100:in `map'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/ffi-1.9.3/lib/ffi/library.rb:100:in `ffi_lib'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/dep_selector-1.0.0.alpha.2/lib/dep_selector/dep_gecode.rb:33:in `<module:Dep_gecode>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/dep_selector-1.0.0.alpha.2/lib/dep_selector/dep_gecode.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/dep_selector-1.0.0.alpha.2/lib/dep_selector/gecode_wrapper.rb:21:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/dep_selector-1.0.0.alpha.2/lib/dep_selector/gecode_wrapper.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/dep_selector-1.0.0.alpha.2/lib/dep_selector/dependency_graph.rb:21:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/dep_selector-1.0.0.alpha.2/lib/dep_selector/dependency_graph.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/dep_selector-1.0.0.alpha.2/lib/dep_selector/selector.rb:21:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/dep_selector-1.0.0.alpha.2/lib/dep_selector/selector.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/dep_selector-1.0.0.alpha.2/lib/dep_selector.rb:22:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/dep_selector-1.0.0.alpha.2/lib/dep_selector.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/solve-1.0.0.rc1/lib/solve/solver.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/solve-1.0.0.rc1/lib/solve/solver.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/solve-1.0.0.rc1/lib/solve.rb:10:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/solve-1.0.0.rc1/lib/solve.rb:10:in `<module:Solve>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/solve-1.0.0.rc1/lib/solve.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bundler/gems/berkshelf-7060813e4887/lib/berkshelf.rb:8:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bundler/gems/berkshelf-7060813e4887/lib/berkshelf.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bundler/gems/berkshelf-7060813e4887/lib/berkshelf/cli.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bundler/gems/berkshelf-7060813e4887/lib/berkshelf/cli.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bundler/gems/berkshelf-7060813e4887/bin/berks:3:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bundler/gems/berkshelf-7060813e4887/bin/berks:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/berks:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/berks:23:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Now I don't know very much about Ruby but I have some experience with C++ and I will never forget these sorts of library linking issues. Only problem is I literally have no idea what I'm supposed to do with this!?

I'm on a mac so I've installed the Gecode dependancy using homebrew. I've tried uninstalling it and re-installing it a few times, I even tried following [this article](http://blog.atwam.com/blog/2013/04/25/building-dep-selector-on-mac-os-x/) but it didn't seem to change anything.

Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need Gecode 3, not 4. 4 is the default, so you need to revert to an old hash and install 3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was seeing the same symptoms, and did a little bit of research onto it. Got it to work by switching gecode versions:

`brew switch gecode 3.7.3`

Then uninstalled the offending gems:

```
gem uninstall berkshelf
gem uninstall solve
gem uninstall dep_selector
```

And finally reinstalling bershelf:

`gem install berkshelf`

Comment: i never knew the brew switch command existed so this really helped me out!

Comment: The version above is not in the homebrew repo anymore. This trick is not working with the current version (4.1.2).

Comment: You're right. I recommend ditching the standalone berkshelf install and instead going with ChefDK: http://www.getchef.com/downloads/chef-dk/

Comment: thank, I did as you wrote and finally my rspec started)